# Stove Pipe Support

Tags: chimney, woodstove

I've got a wood stove i'm looking to replace, and on that journey I will need to remove the current stove for some time to re-tile the hearth.

I have 18' ceilings and several sections of double wall stove pipe - the question is will I need to support/brace the stove pipe after I have removed all the single wall pipe? Any suggestions on how to do so?

[image: my stove pipe]

Answer (score 1):

The reason for single wall at the lower section is to improve the heat exchange. If you change to double or triple wall you won't have as much heat in the room but the pipe won't cool as much and will stay cleaner. If the support from the stove is solid no additional support should be needed as single wall is not as strong as double or triple wall.